# How 2 master nodes share the etcd information in Kubernetes production cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

When having 2 master nodes in the Kubernetes production cluster, do they share their `etcd` database?

Do they have duplication of Etcd each in its own node? or the `etcd should be in a separate machine? how exactly it's working?
In case one master node is dead, does the other master node has all its etcd information?

Comment: Etcd is a clustered db. It runs its own node on each master handling the split internally.

Comment: I don't understand what you say. every master node contains etcd with different details? then how will you recover the data in case the etcd in the master node that is dead?

Comment: The answer lies in stacked etcd topology / external etcd topology has been used in HA K8s cluster.  More details about topology are in following link https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/ha-topology/

Comment: In a basic etcd configuration, every master node contains an identical copy of the data, and etcd handles ensuring it says in sync in a transaction

Comment: yes I think you can post it as the final answer   user1937198
 thank you

Comment: If you got the answer please post it for other community members.